# How to install Picasa on Scientific Linux 6.3?

Tags: software-installation, scientific-linux

I can install/use Picasa with wine, but how can I natively install it from RPM (are there any offical sources to get the installer?)

Comment: There's no native Picasa, the RPM package contains binary wine as well, you're already doing the right stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picasa for Linux (which actually was Picasa for Windows packaged with Wine) is [discontinued](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/spring-cleaning-in-spring.html).

> So today, we’re deprecating Picasa for Linux and will not be maintaining it moving forward.

Your best option would be to run a recent version in Wine.

Comment: wel... this is very sad..